# Could this be related to Universal CRT refactoring?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, msvcrt, crt

I am in the process of upgrading my projects to VS 2015 and only in Debug|x64 configuration I am running into a couple of linker errors when my static library (XXXXX.lib) is being consumed by a DLL:

```
6>XXXXX.lib(stdafx.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vscwprintf referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl ATL::CTrace::TraceV(char const *,int,unsigned int,unsigned int,wchar_t const *,char *)" (?TraceV@CTrace@ATL@@SAXPEBDHIIPEB_WPEAD@Z)

6>XXXXX.lib(stdafx.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPEBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::_System_error_category::message(int)const " (?message@_System_error_category@std@@UEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@H@Z)
```

As you can see, both the referencing function and the unresolved external are both coming from Microsoft's own libraries.

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Why don;t you link the MS libraries where these definitions are coming from?

Comment: Make sure your library `XXXXX.lib` was built with Visual Studio 2015.